# Short syntax for if true then break

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm looking for options of shortening syntax for breaking (and continuing) a loop on a condition

```py
for _ in range(10):
    if condition:
        break
    ...
```

I supposed that short curcuits should work, e.g. `x == 2 and break`, but they cause `SyntaxError`.

What are Python's options for one-line conditioning, except `if condition: break`?

Comment: if condition: break is the pythonnic way to go. I'm unsure there is other alternative. break isn't a statement that can have a value hence it can't be used in any statements requiring a value (as it doesn't even return None as all other statements)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to combine aspects of a `for` and `while` loop, moving the (negated) `break` condition to the loop's head. The condition in the `lambda` can use both variables from the enclosing scope and the current item from the iterable.

```
from itertools import takewhile

for x in takewhile(lambda x: not condition, iterable):
    ...
```

However, while this is shorter (at least in terms of lines), I would not consider it more readable. I would just stick with the explicit `break`.